# Forloop Error on Powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm having some problem with this sentences. The powershell script generated having error due to this for loop.

```
for ($i = 5; $i <=110 -le ; $i+=15)
```

May I know the solutions for this loop please?

Thanks.

The output should be 
5
20
35
50
65
80
95
110

Comment: `$i <=100 -le ;` -> `$i -le 110;`

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 5; $i -le 110; $i += 15) {
  Write-Host $i
}
```

Your syntax is mostly right, but PowerShell doesn't use the '**<=**' style operators at all. Use '**-le**' in it's place and you'll be good to go.

Read more about comparison operators [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators).

Comment: Thanks ! The coding works at last. And thank you for your resources too.